# Issue with event delegation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to clone a table once the table has been populated. Inside the td I placed some input and textarea tags. The problem that I have is that the contents inside the table are not cloned. I have tried to use event delegation, but it seems that I am doing something wrong. 
Here is the JSfiddle, write something inside the table and then press clone.``
http://jsfiddle.net/no84bror/2/

```
  $("#clonetable").on('click','textarea',function(){
    var tempTable = $('#masterTable');
    var temClone = $("<div/>").append(tempTable.clone()).html(); 
   // alert(temClone);
    var rep = temClone.replace("textarea","p");
    $("#a").html(rep);
    });
```

Comment: Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/no84bror/2/

Comment: Code goes in your question please.

Comment: From the [clone() docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#warning): "Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements."

Comment: If you think I answered your question, I'd be delighted if you would click to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a jquery bug  - deep cloning does not work for textareas http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3016
It started as a problem in Firefox but is the same in Chrome, apparently.

"The current behavior is documented at api.jquery.com and of course here. A plugin is available to provide the requested behavior. The ticket is marked patchwelcome, with the caveat that fixing this edge case inside jQuery causes a performance hit for the 90% of the time when it isn't needed."

The following code works and copies the contents of the input field, but due to the above bug you will have to copy the contents of textareas yourself or use the plugin.

```
$("#clonetable").on('click', function(){
     $("#a").html($('#masterTable').clone());
});
```

you can try using `.clone( [withDataAndEvents][, deepWithDataAndEvents] )`, in other words using `.clone(true, true)`, but it makes no difference.

---

Here's the code, including the hack to copy textarea content:

```
 $("#clonetable").on('click',function(){
    $("#a").html($('#masterTable').clone());
    var my_textareas     = $('#masterTable textarea').slice(2,4);
    var result_textareas = $("#a textarea");

    for (var i = 0, l = my_textareas.length; i < l; ++i){
        $(result_textareas[i]).val($(my_textareas[i]).val());
    }
 });
```

Comment: One more thing. If text is placed between the textarea tags right in the html and then run the clone code, it will clone perfectly including the text. Why does it clone correctly when text already exist between the tags?

Comment: Don't know why. Presumably finding and copying stuff loaded with the page is much easier than finding 'dirty' textareas, ie changed later. I'll include the hack to copy the textarea content in my answer, which I found with the bug report somewhere. It works, I tried it in the jsfiddle. Obviously you can't use ids much because the ids are cloned as well so you have duplicate ids.